# App.js not updating modified code in iOS-simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I started using `react native` recently. I've learned that in the new react native update, there is no more `index.ios.js` or `index.android.js`, and that there's only `index.js`. I also learned that there's no need to use `index.js` since there's `App.js`.

The stimulator (iOS) also tells me to simply edit `App.js`. However, every time I try to edit `App.js` and reload the stimulator screen, none of my changes show up and the stimulator screen is left the way it started out. It keeps showing the same words ("Welcome to React Native! To get started, please edit App.js...").

I tried using `react-native start` in the terminal before doing `react-native run-ios`, but that didn't help either.

Does anyone have an idea as to why it isn't working and what can be done to fix it?

This is the code for my index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App.js';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('project2', () => App);
```

Here is screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxqzP.png

Comment: I never worked with it but isn't app.js always generated or something? And maybe you need to have an index? Maybe this article helps: https://medium.com/@spencer_carli/sharing-code-between-android-and-ios-in-react-native-142f6566a0fe not sure if this helps but maybe puts you into the right direction, who knows.

Comment: Can you edit this post and include your changes in `App.js` to show us the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please run the below command, every time when you do changes in the app.js file

**npm run build:ios**